# Есть ли возможность использовать else в сокращённой форме цикла for?

Tags: python, if, for

`1 for x in input() if x in 'aeiou'`
*вот сюда нужно добавить **else***
я сделал обычным циклом

```
for x in text.lower():
    if x in 'aeiouy':
        vowels += 1     
    else:
        consonants += 1
```

Мне интересно, нельзя ли использовать укороченный вариант. Попробовал вот так:

```
vowels = sum(1 if x in 'aeiou' else consonants += 1) for x in input()
```

Выдаёт ошибку `invalid syntax`.

Comment: Куда именно вы хотите добавить else? else в for используется для отлова завершения цикла без break, а тут вы вероятно хотите использовать else для if, тогда нужно что-то вроде `1 if условие else что-то другое for x in input()`. Уточните, что конкретно вы хотите получить.

Comment: `(1 if x in 'aeiou' else 2) for x in input()`  Телепатия сработала?

Comment: @insolor задачу я сделал обычным циклом `for x in text.lower():
    if x in 'aeiouy':
        vowels += 1
    else:
        consonants += 1` но интересно нельзя ли использовать укороченый вариант. Попробовал вот так `vowels = sum(1 if x in 'aeiou' else consonants += 1) for x in input()` - ошибка invalid syntax

Comment: Добавьте пример в сам вопрос.

Comment: @МаксимЖуравель В укороченном варианте можно посчитать что-то одно, Например, `vowels = sum(1 if x in 'aeiouy' else 0 for x in input())` или `vowels = sum(1 for x in input() if x in 'aeiouy')`

Comment: Вообще, если вам нужно две переменные заполнять, то лучше использовать обычный цикл, а не comprehension

Comment: @МаксимЖуравель Можно _испитониться_ и засунуть вычисление обеих переменных в одну строчку: `vowels, consonants = map(sum, (zip(*((1,0) if x in 'aeiouy' else (0,1) for x in input()))))`. Только кроме как академического интереса данный вариант особой ценности не представляет.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, так и сделаю

Answer (score 1):

В генераторах последовательностей если вы пишите `if` после цикла, то он служит фильтром для выходной последовательности, и писать там `else` нельзя. Да и что бы оно там означало, если `if` управляет по генератором по True/False.

```
a = [x for x in [0, 1, 2, 3] if X > 1]
# на выходе a = [2, 3]
```

Если `if` стоит до цикла, то он управляет значением, которое попадёт в выходную последовательность, и `else` там быть обязано (т.к. в последовательность что-то же должно попасть.

```
a = ["A" if x > 2 else "B" for x in [0, 1, 2, 3] ]
# на выходе a = ["B", "B", "B", "A"]
```

И можно оба варианта комбинировать.

```
a = ["A" if x > 2 else "B" for x in [0, 1, 2, 3] if x > 1]
# на выходе a = ["B", "A"]
```

---

Можно, конечно, из академического интереса изгольнуться и сделать вычисления нескольких переменных в одной последовательность. Но у такого кода читаемость сильно хромает.

```
vowels, consonants = map(sum, (zip(*((1,0) if x in 'aeiouy' else (0,1) for x in input()))))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

как метко выразился @GrAnd в комментариях, можно "испитониться" и засунуть вычисления обеих переменных в одну строчку, еще таким способом:

```
text = 'my test text'
v = c = 0

[(v:= v+1) if i in 'aeiouy' else (c:= c+1) for i in text.lower()]

print(f'{v=}, {c=}')  # v=3, c=9
```

справедливости ради, надо заметить, что ваш код (как и этот) считает не количество гласных и согласных в тексте, а количество гласных и НЕгласных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Кажется решил проблему НЕгласных методом isalpha()